# Hide unused time slots in a weekly view calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a calendar that I have placed on a site page that uses the weekly view. My organization uses GMT (Zulu) time and that is the regional time zone used. The calendar in the weekly view takes up too much real estate on the page and users have to scroll down to see the information. We do not have any entries from 0700 to 1100. Is there a way to hide those specific time frames kind of like you can hide the weekends on the weekly view with a script editor? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a classic page to place calendar web part?

If true, we could display week day/hide weekend, it isn’t possible to hide specific time in calendar and we don’t suggest you do that.

If not, please provide more information such as which web part you put on modern page. For Events web part, you could choose date range and decide the number of items to show up.

[image]